# angular 2/4 conditional component routing?

Tags: angular, routes

I want all my login/notlogin page in the same route, let's say root "/", can we set different component to the path "" in different conditions?

Below it's my routes settings. If it's possible that I can set the path: '' to HomeComponent when it's logged in, 
and set path:'' to UnauthorizedHomeComponent when it's not logged in? Please see the comment below

my routes setting:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent, // Want to set to UnauthorizedHomeComponent while not logged in
  { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent,canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
  { path: 'profile', component: ProfileComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent }
];
export const AppRouting = RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { 
  useHash: true
});
```

In my app.module

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    RegisterComponent,
    ProfileComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    DashboardComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    FormsModule,
    CustomFormsModule,
    AppRouting  //Routes
  ],
  providers: [AuthService, AuthGuard, JwtHelper],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Just use a wrapping component, and use *ngIf to display one or the other.

Comment: was thinking the similar approach, is it a proper way to do it?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be? And would I advise it if I thought it is a bad idea?

Comment: cool thanks for advise.  I'll try

Answer (score 0):

Can't we use `Router.navigate([])` from home to decide where to land?
For example

```
export class HomeComponent {
   loggedIn:boolean = true;
   constructor(private router:Router){}

   ngOnInit(){
     if(!this.loggedIn){
        this.router.navigate(["/login"]);
     }
   }
}

@NgModule({
   declarations: [
      AppComponent, HomeComponent, UnAuthHomeComponent
   ],
   imports: [
      BrowserModule, FormsModule,
      RouterModule.forRoot([
        {path: '', component: HomeComponent},
        {path: 'shopping', component: ShoppingComponent},
        .....
      ])
   ],
   bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule{

}
```

Here control will come to `HomeComponent` and upon your condition you can navigate to your desired component.